Balance longtblr at the end of two column mode
I have a long table using the tabularray package.
It spans over at least one page in two column mode. Breaking after a column is done works perfectly fine, however on the last page all of the table is on the left.
As it is a checklist, I would rather have the column balance out. I inserted \\* At every point where information should stay together. This means everywhere breaking is possible i dont care if the column is broken or not. Is there any way to achive this? The packages balance and flushend dont seem to work.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\DefTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{default}{}
\DefTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{default}{}
\DefTblrTemplate{caption}{default}{}
\DefTblrTemplate{conthead}{default}{}
\DefTblrTemplate{capcont}{default}{}


\usepackage[left=1.2cm,right=1.7cm,top=1cm,bottom=1.8cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn

\begin{longtblr}{
    colspec = {Q[c!,white]Q[c!,white]Q[l,white]},
    hlines, vlines,
    rowhead=1,
    }

    \textbf{Ist} & \textbf{Soll} & \textbf{Bezeichnung} \\\hline
    \SetCell[c=3]{l}\textbf{Modul 1}                    \\*
                 & 1             & A                    \\*
                 & 2             & B                    \\*
                 & 3             & C                    \\*
                 & 4             & D                    \\*
                 & 5             & E                    \\*
                 & 6             & F                    \\
    \SetCell[c=3]{l}{\textbf{Modul 2}}                  \\*
                 & 1             & A                    \\*
                 & 2             & B                    \\*
                 & 3             & C                    \\*
                 & 4             & D                    \\*
                 & 5             & E                    \\*
                 & 6             & F                    \\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}

The desired look would be achieved by inserting a \pagebreak before the second \SetCell command. As I want to automatically generate the pdf I'd rather not do this manually.
Thanks in advance :)
